# EPPlus isn't shown in NuGet

Tags: nuget, epplus

If I try and install package EPPlus via NuGet in Visual Studio 2017 it says it's not found.  What's the trick to making this work?

I can see a ton of other package, but not EPPlus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Package Manager Console in VS 2017

(**Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console**), and enter the following into the Console;

*Install-Package EPPlus -Version 4.5.2.1*